# Алгоритм отправления уведомления

Tags: алгоритм, уведомления

У меня андроид приложение типа соц. сети. И там есть функции лайк, коммент, подписка. Теперь надо реализовать отправку уведомления к приложению при обновлении вышеперечисленных функций. На первый взгляд кажется просто. Думал что после всех новых лайков, комментов отправлю уведомление к пользователю все. Но оказалось очень сложным)

Дело в том что среди пользователей будут популярные пользователи, у которых на каждый пост приходит множество лайков, комментов почти что ежесекундно. И если каждое действие отправить как уведомление, то по просту это будет надоедать пользователя, и ещё телефон безостановочно будет звучать о новом уведомлении. 
Как можно это сделать красиво?

Как вообще работают соц сети ФБ ВК и т.д?

И ещё один не маловажный вопрос, как проверять пришло ли новое уведомление максимально сэкономив на батарею и мб данные если сделать самостоятельные запросы на сервер ?

Например как это делает Telegram, что сообщение приходит мгновенно, но при этом и батарея и мб данные пользуются экономично.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм отправки пуш уведомлений вам нужно реализовать на стороне сервера, с которым взаимодействует ваше Андроид приложение. В мобильном приложении вам нужно зарегистрировать устройство на сервисе пуш уведомлений, получить `token` и затем отправить его на сервере с данным о текущем устройстве и пользователе.

На стороне сервера уже разработать алгоритм для построения пуш уведомлений. Где расставить приоритеты и сортировать кол-во уведомлений в зависимости от текущего пользователя приложения.

Советую вам использовать один из сервисов для реализации отправки пуш уведомлений:

- **Google Cloud Messaging** https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
- **Amazon SNS Mobile Push Notifications** http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html
- **Azure Notification Hubs** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/
- **Urban Airship** https://www.urbanairship.com/

Comment: Отлично! Ещё как проверять пришло ли новое уведомление максимально сэкономив на батарею и мб данные если сделать самостоятельные запросы на сервер ?